# How to use database library with Robot Framework on temporary sql server

Tags: robotframework

I am using Robot Framework's database library which supports database validation.

I tried to execute this basic command:

```
***Variables***
***Settings***
Suite Setup  
Suite Teardown  
Test Setup  
Test Teardown  
Library  DatabaseLibrary
***Testcases***
UC_DB_Validation
```

To connect to the Database I'm using:

```
dbapiModuleName=Mysqldb  dbName='bigetestsrv'  dbUsername='ravitest'  dbPassword='welcome'  dbHost='10.73.92.18'
```

When running the connection string from command prompt using pybot I get the following error:

```
"No Module Named as Mysqldb"
```

I am using Query Express with valid credentials and I do not have a Sql Server installed in my machine.

How can I connect to my DB?

Comment: In case anyone else is having problems connecting to SQL Server via DatabaseLibrary:  I used the pyodbc module with DatabaseLibrary.  The DatabaseLibrary "Connect to Database" keyword doesn't work with pyodbc when connecting to modern versions of SQL Server, perhaps because the DatabaseLibrary specifies the very old "SQL Server" ODBC driver instead of a more modern driver.  So use the "Connect to Database Using Custom Params" keyword.  However, there is a catch: You must enclose the second argument, that specifies the connection string, in quotes to get it to work.

Answer (score 2):

I got .....

I was approaching in a wrong way
The Database Library (Apache License) from
**http://franz-see.github.com/Robotframework-Database-Library/** i am using is currently tested only with postgresql using psycopg2, it may or may not work with other RDBMS.
So I tried it to connect pymssql db, which is supporting bydefualt and it worked.

I used 
Connect To Database Using Custom Params  pymssql  'dbname', 'username', 'password', 'host'

As a prerequisite i need to install Pymssql (GNU Lesser General Public License) from 
**http://pymssql.sourceforge.net/license.php**

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Instead of :

```
dbapiModuleName=Mysqldb
```

Use :

```
dbapiModuleName=PyMySQL
```

Also, Please make sure `PyMySQL` module is installed in your machine using `pip` command.